# C# Dataset SQL select in

Tags: c#, sql, report

i use cloture.xsd. i connect this to my Report Cloture_Tete.

in SQL it works:

```
SELECT     NO_ORDRE, CODE_CLIENT, CODE_DEST, STATUT_ORDRE, RS_NOM, ADRESSE, CP, VILLE, PAYS, INSEE, SIRET, TEL, FAX, EMAIL, ENLEV_UNITE, ENLEV_CREMB, 
                      ENLEV_DECL, MODAL_MODE, MODAL_PORT, MODAL_SPEC, LIVRS_EXPRS, LIVRS_SIGN, LIVRS_SAMD, NBR_COLIS, POID, POID_COR, CODE_MAG, OBS, 
                      DATE_CREE, DATE_MODIF, CREE_PAR, MODIF_PAR, REF_EXPED, AUTRE_REF, DATE_CLOTUR, AGENCE, TRANSPORTEUR, CHAUFFEUR, FACTURATION
FROM         ORDRE
WHERE     (STATUT_ORDRE = 2) AND (TRANSPORTEUR IN (1, 2))
```

but when i do via C#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string CHAUFFEUR = Request.QueryString["CHAUFFEUR"];
        string CODE_CLIENT = Request.QueryString["ClientID"];
        string ClotList = Request.QueryString["ClotList"];
        try
        {
            using (var connectionWrapper = new Connexion())
            {
                ReportViewer_Cloture.Report = new Cloture_Tete(Convert.ToInt32(CHAUFFEUR), CODE_CLIENT, ClotList);


            }
        }
        catch (Exception excThrown)
        {
            throw new Exception(excThrown.Message);
        }
    }
```

with my predefine Select in cloture.xsd:

```
SELECT ADRESSE, AGENCE, AUTRE_REF, CHAUFFEUR, CODE_CLIENT, CODE_DEST, CODE_MAG, CP, CREE_PAR, DATE_CLOTUR, DATE_CREE, DATE_MODIF, EMAIL, ENLEV_CREMB, ENLEV_DECL, ENLEV_UNITE, FACTURATION, FAX, INSEE, LIVRS_EXPRS, LIVRS_SAMD, LIVRS_SIGN, MODAL_MODE, MODAL_PORT, MODAL_SPEC, MODIF_PAR, NBR_COLIS, NO_ORDRE, OBS, PAYS, POID, POID_COR, REF_EXPED, RS_NOM, SIRET, STATUT_ORDRE, TEL, TRANSPORTEUR, VILLE FROM ORDRE WHERE (STATUT_ORDRE = 2) AND (TRANSPORTEUR IN (@Trans))
```

and i look with my SQL Profiler it produce:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT ADRESSE, AGENCE, AUTRE_REF, CHAUFFEUR, CODE_CLIENT, CODE_DEST, CODE_MAG, CP, CREE_PAR, DATE_CLOTUR, DATE_CREE, DATE_MODIF, EMAIL, ENLEV_CREMB, ENLEV_DECL, ENLEV_UNITE, FACTURATION, FAX, INSEE, LIVRS_EXPRS, LIVRS_SAMD, LIVRS_SIGN, MODAL_MODE, MODAL_PORT, MODAL_SPEC, MODIF_PAR, NBR_COLIS, NO_ORDRE, OBS, PAYS, POID, POID_COR, REF_EXPED, RS_NOM, SIRET, STATUT_ORDRE, TEL, TRANSPORTEUR, VILLE FROM ORDRE WHERE (STATUT_ORDRE = 2) AND (TRANSPORTEUR IN (@Trans))',N'@Trans varchar(50)',@Trans='1,2'
```

it not work, Why the different is just `(TRANSPORTEUR IN (1, 2))` in SQL and `(TRANSPORTEUR IN (@Trans))',N'@Trans varchar(50)',@Trans='1,2'`

thanks you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `IN (@Trans)`, you are saying (essentially) `IN ('1,2')`, which is very different to saying `IN (1,2)`. Specifically, it compared against a **single** string, rather than multiple values. There are various "split" UDF implementations that you might find useful (i.e. call a UDF and inner-join to the data).

Comment: Thanks you for your response. can you give me a hint how can i construct a (1, 2) ? should i work on C# side or SQL side ?

Comment: @user609511 it depends on the tools available ;p String concatenation is a bit risky unless you **know** the content is safe. Generally, you'd need the TSQL to have the right number of elements. Our own tool (dapper) does this for us, allowing us to just use "where id in @foo" (it adds the brackets and expands the parameters from a list etc). More generally, the UDF approach is pretty common and safe